# Spring Batch Job No Errors from Writer but db does not update

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

Sorry, can not add code here. I will try to explain as much as possible.

Entities: Database 1 (MySQL-has User Table), Database 2 (MySQL- Empty), SpringBatch Job

Working condition: When I run SpringBatch Job to read the User data from Database 1 and process it and write it, the code works. The table gets updated. But spring batch also creates its meta data on this database (i.e Database 1).

New condition: When I configure SpringBatch to use new DataSource (i.e. Database 2) for its metadata, everything works except ItemWriter does not write the updated User data to Database 1.There are no errors on the terminal and it says that data writing was successful. So basically in this situation: Reading from Database 1 is all good, writing BATCH METADATA to Database 2 by Batch is all good, ItemWriter says it has updated data to the User table in Database 1 after processing but I don't see the change.

Experimentation:

- Correct data is coming inside ItemReader, verified by logging
- ItemProcessor is working as except, here it auto capitalizes the names of Users.
- Valid Processed Data is coming to the ItemWriter, verified by logging.
- If I remove a column from the User Table manually, the writer throws error by saying that it could not write to the table since that particular column does not exist. This proves the writer is detecting the correct table with correct repository.
- But when everything is valid, Writer says data has been updated in table but there is no changes when I look into the table.

Any suggestion why?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it will be hard to identify the root cause of that issue. Which `ItemWriter` implementation do you use? Did you set the target datasource on that `ItemWriter`? Which transaction manager do you use? If you try to create an "anonymous" [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue without sharing the actual code, I will try to help.

Comment: I am not being able to edit this post. How can I edit it to add code snippets?